# python: How to check if a document exist in Elasticsearch using a doc _id

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Is there any way, through any of the pythonic Elasticsearch libraries, to check if a document exist in a given index using the `_id` field?

Say I have a random doc _id of 73H316Dhgh and I want to check if it exists on a given index? How would I go about this using either of the python Elasticsearch libraries?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`get` method](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.get) to get the document:

```
es.get(index="my-index", id="73H316Dhgh")
```

Otherwise if you don't need the full document, but just check for existence, you can use the [`exists` method](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.exists):

```
es.exists(index="my-index", id="73H316Dhgh")
```